# Can an AJAX object be used for one way communications?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to retreive data from a form using a javascript call. From there I need to send the data to a php script that inserts it in to a database. I have an AJAX call that does this...but I know that the AJAX call monitors for a response from there Server. This will work but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it, i.e. a way to do it with out "monitoring" the server for a response.

Comment: If you make an asynchronous ajax call, nothing is delayed on either end.

Comment: Still, the Ajax object is watching for a response very vigilantly I might add.  Consider , perhaps meditate on this a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the fire-and-forget pattern for some ideas as to how to do this, and lessons learned.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajaxian-fire-and-forget-pattern

There are some lessons there that didn't seem obvious to me, such as this nugget:

> We noticed that if we fired off a lot of XHR requests, we would max at 5, 
>   and the others died.

Comment: @Chris Aaker - There is no proper way, just various hacks. One approach I did was to spawn a thread on the server-side, immediately return a response and have the thread do the processing.  This allows for rapid requests as the response is almost immediate.  So the best approach depends on your needs, how many requests, how quickly are you designing for?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax gets the response from the server it doesn't need to do anything with it. Asynchronous Ajax calls won't block the page that is calling it either.

The server doesn't/can't wait for the response to be received before it processes anything (so I don't think you have a problem to start with).

The server will process the request as soon as it is received. The response being sent back doesn't affect how soon the server can start processing.

Comment: There would be two way data flow, but asynchronous calls work with a callback, it won't block the script and when it gets a response it will invoke the function for the callback (if there is one).

Comment: Yea that should be fine. What makes you think its not working as you expect?